Problemas de alineación en diseño responsive con columnas CSS
Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto web donde tengo un diseño de tres columnas utilizando CSS flexbox para hacerlo responsive. Sin embargo, estoy experimentando problemas de alineación en la columna derecha cuando el contenedor "ranking" tiene contenido.
Este es el código que uso:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.column {
  padding: 10px;
}

.column-center {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-left,
.column-right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column-center {
    order: 1;
  }
  .column-left {
    order: 2;
    height: auto;
  }
  .column-right {
    order: 3;
    height: auto;
  }
}
<body>
  <div class="column column-left">
    <!-- Contenido de la columna izquierda -->
  </div>
  <div class="column column-center">
    <!-- Contenido de la columna del centro -->
  </div>
  <div id="column-right" class="column column-right">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-text">Command Prompt</div>
        <div class="title-bar-controls">
          <button aria-label="Minimize"></button>
          <button aria-label="Maximize"></button>
          <button aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="window-body">
        <pre>Microsoft&#10094;R&#10095; Windows DOS 
          &#10094;C&#10095; Copyright Microsoft Corp 1990-2001.
                <br>C:&#92;WINDOWS&#92;SYSTEM32> type ./ranking
              </pre>
        <div id="ranking">
          <pre id="top1">  1. </pre>
          <pre id="top2">  2. </pre>
          <pre id="top3">  3. </pre>
          <pre id="top4">  4. </pre>
          <pre id="top5">  5. </pre>
          <pre id="top6">  6. </pre>
          <pre id="top7">  7. </pre>
          <pre id="top8">  8. </pre>
          <pre id="top9">  9. </pre>
          <pre id="top10"> 10. </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>



Como explicaba, si el contenedor está vacío los estilos se aplican correctamente:

Y al poner los <pre> deja de tener el comportamiento esperado:

Como se ve en las imágenes, estoy utilizando xp.css, he intentado asegurarme de que no es el principal problema, quitando estos estilos la pagina se comporta exactamente igual, al llenar el contenedor de elementos, ya sean <pre>, <p>, <h1>, etc, deja de alinearse donde deberia.
Soy novato y no consigo entender del todo el problema, así que agradezco de antemano cualquier respuesta.

Prueba esto:
Puse un overflow: scroll; para la mediaquery en column-right. Luego un height: auto tambien para el column center.
Tambien saco el margin y padding 0 de body, esto ya lo defines en el * que significa a todos los elementos.
Vamos probando poco a poco
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
}

.column-center,
.column-left,
.column-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-left,
.column-right {
  flex: 1;
}

.column-center {
  flex: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column-center {
    order: 1;
    height: auto;
  }
  .column-left {
    order: 2;
    height: auto;
  }
  .column-right {
    order: 3;
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}

